# Webpack: how to handle the finish of build process?

Tags: webpack

Webpack: how to handle the finish of build process, and do some stuff with the bundle.css/bundle.js? Is it possible to provide a callback function that will be called once the building is finished?

Comment: are you using the node api or the cli?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using two ways :

1. **npm script**

   Just run your custom script after completing your webpack build

   `build: webpack && node ./your-script.js`
2. **using webpack plugin**

   You can opt for some third party webpack plugin like [on-build-webpack](https://www.npmjs.com/package/on-build-webpack)

Comment: Thank you a lot! The second option does solve the issue :)